# Account formula field to get the latest opportunity / quote contact name?

Tags: formula, formula-field

An odd request, I know.

What I'm looking for is a formula on the Account object that grabs the most recent Contact name that is assigned to an opportunity / quote.

Is this possible with a formula or should I be creating a flow to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible via a roll-up rather than a formula. Unfortunately out of the box roll-ups won't do this. Look at [Roll-Up Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI)  or [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) and upvote this [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjVQUAZ/rollup-summary-for-standard-relationships-on-account-assets-cases-and-contacts)

Comment: ...another, perhaps easier option is a dynamic, _admin_-filtered related list available in Summer 22: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdimuUAB/intelligent-related-lists-filterable-by-admin . Whether it will go down to the level of filtering that you need is a question mark but worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use a formula by itself to do this because there is a many-to-one relationship between Opportunities and Accounts and similarly, complex relationships between Contacts and Quotes. Formulas are not able to reference multiple children or multiple records that look up to the record with the formula on it.

You will need to use a flow or an Apex trigger to grab this data when the associated record is updated.

[image: Standard Sales Cloud Objects data model. Many-to-one relationship between Opportunity and Account. Many-to-one relationship between Contact and Account. Many-to-many from Quote to Opportunity & Quote to Contact.]